# How to detect an android device whether it supports google maps API

Tags: android

I am currently developing an android application uses Google map API.

I am wondering do all android devices support map API, becuase this api is an optinal api and it is an add-on to the platform.

I am worried that my application won't be able to run on that device.

What I need to know is programatically detect wether the device support map API, and catch the exception and do something else.

Because, using map capability is only one of features of my application, I would like to let those devices that don't support map api can still download and run my application with out effecting other features of my app.

Any comment or suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all your guys help! all of your suggestion are useful to me!!

I wrote a simple application that is able to deployed on None-Google-Map API emulator, and detect presence of Google API problematically.

What I did was I specifying `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="false" />`

(but android "required" attribute only works for 2.1 and doesn't work for 1.6. I will need to find out why. cos when I had look at the documentation, it says that this attributed supported by 1.6)

Thus, I am able to deploy the application on to emulator.

Secondly, I created a map activity which is called HelloMaps
In my main activity

```
try{
     mapActivity = new Intent(TestApp.this, HelloMaps.class); 
     startActivityForResult(mapActivity, 0); 
}catch(NoClassDefFoundError e){
(Toast.makeText(TestApp.this, "Google Map API not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)).show(); 
}
```

This will catch the exception and tell me that the device couldn't run map activity.

Answer (score 15):

I have used following solution in addition to described

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="false"/>
```

in another answers:

```
public void mapClick(View view)
{
    try
    {
        // check if Google Maps is supported on given device
        Class.forName("com.google.android.maps.MapActivity");

        this.startActivity(new Intent(this, MyMapActivity.class));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        UIUtils.showAlert(this, R.string.google_maps_not_found);
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to fail on samsung galaxy tab with android 3.2 and on virtualbox with android x86 2.2

Comment: How can this fail??? its whether the class exists, or not...
Perhaps a null check can be added if the class is null then throw an exception in case it is null. This simply cannot fail, otherwise, Java would be a very lame language. ;)

Comment: Maybe he means: "it doesn't detect the presence of Google Maps, when it should, as it is present" ??

Comment: @max4ever I've tested on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1" and A Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7", both running Android 4.0.3, and the above code works. I have a user reporting problems on a Samsung Galaxy S II, but I can't reproduce it on one here running 4.0.3. Perhaps it's a bug that Samsung fixed?

Answer (score 5):

I needed to see if the library existed before attempting any calling, so I could fill the relevant preferences before-hand.  Here's the code I came up with to check.

```
public static boolean hasSystemSharedLibraryInstalled(Context ctx,
        String libraryName) {
    boolean hasLibraryInstalled = false;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(libraryName)) {
        String[] installedLibraries = ctx.getPackageManager()
                .getSystemSharedLibraryNames();
        if (installedLibraries != null) {
            for (String s : installedLibraries) {
                if (libraryName.equals(s)) {
                    hasLibraryInstalled = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return hasLibraryInstalled;
}
```

And then I check to see if `com.google.android.maps` is installed.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, some Devices, like Archos 5IT and Some Tablet does not have Google Maps, Android Market, etc...

Here is my Code.
BelgianMap is a MapActivity:

```
try {
    Intent i = new Intent(InfoGare.this, BelgianMap.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Google Map not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But maybe there is an other way to find that at the creation of your application and display a message. That might be better.

Comment: This will work and has good redundancy. However if you simply don't want the users to be able to use the app then the solution I posted may be more fitting, and I think it is essential if you are using the googlemaps API.

Comment: You are right! Thank a lot for the information, that will help me a lot!

Comment: Thanks very much. your code works for me. but I need to catch NoClassDefFoundError instead .

Comment: I like this solution simply because it gives me the opportunity to open a webview with the url for google maps (maps.google.com) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Use the (undocumented?) uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" **android:required="false"** in the manifest. This will allow installation in a maps-api non-supported device.

Then check this out:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html

You can still have all your maps-api code intact in the app (no need for 2 versions), just code your UI to prevent running it. (In my case I greyed-out a preference). As noted, technique outlined above effectively predicts something that won't work, and allows you to respond (no FCs), instead of just reacting to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The optional API just applies to the emulator as far as I know. The 2 different version of the API levels is only for the emulator, real devices should all have the maps API I think

Comment: No.. For instance, the Archos 5IT (or some other tablets) does not Have Google Maps ( and does not Have Android Matket neither).

Comment: Yes. some tablets doesn't have Google Maps. I tested on a real tablet device, when I install my map activity, it gives me install failed error message.

Comment: The Casio G'Zone Command does not come with Google Maps pre-installed, it has B#$#%##ing maps installed (and I can't uninstall it!).

Comment: Not all devices have Google Maps, e.g. the Kindle Fire.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using googlemaps in your application you should include the following in your manifest.xml inside the application tags

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

This will either prevent a user from installing your application or seeing it in the market, not sure which, maybe both.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The Android market would filter out the app for the user. However, I would like to allow user to download my app not only from market but from my site. Because, using map capability is only one of features of my application, I would like to let those devices that doesn't support map api are still able to download and run my application with out effecting other features of my app.

Comment: android :required = "false" helped me to installed my map application onto an none-google api supported emulator (2.1), at least I didn't get "Missing shared library" error message. However, this attribute doesn't work for 1.6 by some how, I coudn't compile, I am getting "No resouce identifier found for 'required' error message when I am compling project

Comment: To bypass the compilation error you could raise the target version to 2.1 and then set minsdkversion to 4. This would make it compile but 1.6 and below will ignore the required=false (I think)

Comment: Yes!! if I do so, it allows me to compile, but 1.6 still ignore the required = false, and give me "Missing shared library" error message. See another post of mine 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436674/uses-library-in-androidmanifest-xml

Answer (score 0):

By using `adb`, To prints all system libraries:

```
adb shell cmd package list libraries
```

If your device supports Google Maps, you'll see this line:

```
library:com.google.android.maps
```