# uses-library in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

I currently have this in my AndroidManifest.xml

**uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required = "false"**

The specified requirement of google map api is not compulsory. (This enables me to install my application on an none-google-api emulator)

However, this only works for API level 7, Platform 2.1 
**It doesn't work for API level 4, Platform 1.6**

I am getting an error message when I am compiling - " **No resource identifier found for attribute 'required" in package 'android'**

But, when I looked at the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

The attribute 'required' is introduced since level 4.

Could somebody help me out!

---

Thanks Aillyn

I think it impossible to include required attribute in uses-library tag.

Is there a way to include uses-library in the java code rather than in the AndroidManifest.xml??

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Android doc got updated:

attributes:

```
android:required
    Boolean value that indicates whether the application requires the library specified by android:name:

        "true": The application does not function without this library. The system will not allow the application on a device that does not have the library.
        "false": The application can use the library if present, but is designed to function without it if necessary. The system will allow the application to be installed, even if the library is not present. If you use "false", you are responsible for checking at runtime that the library is available.

        To check for a library, you can use reflection to determine if a particular class is available.

    The default is "true".

    Introduced in: API Level 7.
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html

Answer (score 2):

`uses-library` has no `required` attribute. From [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html):

```
<uses-library android:name="string" />
```

And you should use that for Google maps. From [Google's docs:](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#useslibrary)

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

The one that has the `required` attribute is `uses-feature`

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="integer"
              android:name="string"
              android:required=["true" | "false"] />
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but I was able to put required attribute for Platform 2.1

Comment: @TS.xy You weren't supposed to.

Comment: Thanks Aillyn, Is there a way to inlcude uses-libarary in the java code rather than in the AndroidManifest.xml??

Comment: @TS.xy Not sure if that's possible