# Use of google map library on manifest file

Tags: android, google-maps

Why do we use the below code on our android manifest file.Can anyone please explain?

```
        <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />
```

Comment: @ Shanto George i dont think this entry must be in AndroidManifest.xml.
please go through to this [link1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) and [link2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html)

Comment: Hai Lakshay, do you know the usage of this library com.google.android.maps?

Comment: I think this will [clear your doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7845740/5308778)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out : [uses-library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html). This will give the clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

uses-library tells the android system that the app requires com.google.android.maps package to be installed in device ie Google maps app

if you put required attribute true, `android:required="true"` , then the app will be installed only if device has google maps installed in it.