# How to make "uses-library" optional in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have built an android app which use Google Map feature. I want my app installed on phones which does not install Google Map, in that case, I would disable the map feature.

There is a "uses-library" tag in manifest file, what can I do with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@CommonsWare: I think you are refering to **android:required** and not to **android:enabled**

Something like this:

```
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented `android:enabled` attribute on `<uses-library>`. However, Dianne Hackborn mentioned it in a discussion, telling us to use it, so I am hoping that this is a documentation error and that it is truly supported.

Having `android:enabled="false"`, then using reflection to see if `MapActivity` exists, should give you what you need, AFAIK.

Comment: I add android:enabled="false", but I got "INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY" when I tried to install it in a emulator without google map.

Comment: @virsir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909903/disable-mapview-if-it-is-not-supported -- according to that person who tried it, it only works on 2.0 and higher. What version are you trying it on?

Comment: The question you mentioned uses "android:required" but not "android:enabled", is that something different?

Comment: @virsir: D'oh! My earlier answer was right, it's `android:required="false"`. My sincere apologies.

Comment: You are right, i just test that with /android:required="false"/ and yes, it can not build in 1.5 or 1.6 sdk. I think I should build with 2.1 sdk and set minSdkVersion to 3.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use reflection.  Make your map activity a Singleton and create an interface for its public methods. Then use a try catch to check if the class exists via class loader. If so, in the try, call start activity.  If you need to interact withe class then declare an instance of the type interface as a data member and use reflection to interact with it.