# Android - Google MAP API and Internal GPS support

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, gps

1) Does all android phone have Internal GPS?
2) How do we find out if the android phone supports Google Map library through code?
3) If Google map API is not supported, can we bundle it along with our application to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sivaram.

Answer (score 1):

Not all android phones are GPS equipped..
You need to check it using code....

One easy way is to catch Exception and do further processing accordingly..

Google Map API are already bundled in the target API You select . son need for any check....

Comment: How to check the presence of Inernal GPS through code? Also I have seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410475/how-to-detect-an-android-device-whether-it-supports-google-maps-api which works out detection of Google map API for Android 2.0 & above. But how to detect on Android 1.5 & 1.6? In case if the phone does not support Google Map API, how can we have mapping solution developed?

Answer (score 1):

If the phone doesnt support Google Maps - could you call a URL (which would direct to your own web page) with the Google Maps API displaying the web page thru a webkit browser - ok the maps wouldnt be "in" the phone - but displayed in the phone (albeit thru a web browser) which the user really wouldnt be aware of.

Comment: I agree on that. But, is there any possibility to bring the Map API to the android phone if it is not already available instead of accessing it over internet?

Comment: I think that it will get bundled with the application if you select "Google API" from the Eclipse SDK..... (I think....).

Comment: For development purpose, we can handle it. But what about when the application is to be installed in an android phone which doesn't support Google Map API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use network to detect position instead of GPS

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location cur_location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```