# Do I need to have a google map app pre-installed on the device to be able to run an app using the google API?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an app that uses the google API. I would like to know if i install that app on a mobile phone, will it require a gooogle map app pre-installed in the device to be able to use the map or it uses the internet to get the map from google or any other methods?

This my main.java:

> package com.map.testing;
>
> import android.os.Bundle;
>
> import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint; import
>   com.google.android.maps.MapActivity; import
>   com.google.android.maps.MapController; import
>   com.google.android.maps.MapView;
>
> public class main extends MapActivity {
>       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>       MapController mControl;
>       GeoPoint GeoP;
>       MapView mapV;         @Override
>       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           setContentView(R.layout.main);
>       mapV = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
>       mapV.displayZoomControls(true);
>       mapV.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
>
> ```
> double lat =  23.1;
> double longi = 113.3;
>
> GeoP = new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6), (int)(longi*1E6));
>
> mControl = mapV.getController();
> mControl.animateTo(GeoP);
> mControl.setZoom(12);
>
> }
>
> @Override 
> protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {        
> // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
> return false; 
> }
> ```
>
> }

---

This my main.xml:

> ```
> <com.google.android.maps.MapView
>              android:id="@+id/mapView"
>              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>              android:enabled="true"
>              android:clickable="true"
>              android:apiKey="00_sJY0o9guZejQwsJOr8PPDHtMpnEB6LWFspjA"
>              />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

---

my manifest:

> ```
> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>
> <application
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name" >
>     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".main"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you can handle id the api is not on phone by

android:required="false" in

[How to detect an android device whether it supports google maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410475/how-to-detect-an-android-device-whether-it-supports-google-maps-api)